# Alternative of FBML for render facebook friends via Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, fbjs, serverfbml

Here is some trouble with Facebook API we are facing from last monday.
We use FBML(Facebook markup language) for sending invitation to facebook friends(There is no problem in login to facebook from our app.) which is in phase of deprecation by Facebook.
On Jan 1, 2012: FBML will no longer be supported on Platform. June 1, 2012: FBML apps will no longer work. All FBML endpoints are removed. You can find more here:

[developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/)

```
function renderInviteFriends(contDiv) {
var htmlfb = "<span class='frnd-heading'>Facebook friends who are not yet using fipeo</span> <br /><br />";
htmlfb += "<fb:serverFbml width=\"" + width_of_invitation_div + "\"><script type=\"text/fbml\"><fb:fbml><fb:request-form action=" + window.location + " method='REQUEST' invite=true type='" + type_of_fb_request_form + "' ";
htmlfb += " content='<fb:req-choice url=\"" + baseUrl + "\" label=\"Accept\" />" + content_of_fb_request_form + "'>";
if (exclude_ids.length > 0)
    htmlfb += " <fb:multi-friend-selector cols=" + column_count_fb_multi_friend_selector + " exclude_ids=\"" + exclude_ids + "\" actiontext=\"" + actiontext_fb_multi_friend_selector + "\"/>";
else
    htmlfb += " <fb:multi-friend-selector cols=" + column_count_fb_multi_friend_selector + " actiontext=\"" + actiontext_fb_multi_friend_selector + "\"/>";
htmlfb += " </fb:request-form></fb:fbml></script></fb:serverFbml>";
document.getElementById(contDiv).innerHTML = htmlfb;
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById(contDiv));
}
```

Now the alternative of FBML is FBJS.
If someone already done R&D on these changes and overcome from this problem please share with us. Please remember we use Javascript SDK for facebook API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Requests Dialog`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) with [`FB.ui`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) to invite users with [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

BTW, [FBJS](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/) will be deprecated same time as [FBML](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/)

Comment: I am trying Request dialog with FB.ui as you suggested. but there is some issues with it. Application request is send by user is perfect but FB friends are not able to see "Accept" button. and how can add a accept button without FBML in this case.